# Android : Adjust Soft Keyboard not working

Tags: java, android

I have the following layout file :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    >

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:elevation="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/custom_button_grey"
        >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/listing_image"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/background_title" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/listing_title"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/robotoregular"
                android:text="Title"
                android:textColor="@color/font"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/sdfsd"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Listed by :"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:textColor="@color/font"
                />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/listing_author"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Some random guy"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:textColor="@color/font"
                />
        </LinearLayout>

    </TableRow>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll"
        android:stackFromBottom="true"/>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/input_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/custom_button"
            android:ems="10"
            android:fontFamily="@font/robotoregular"
            android:hint="Chat here..."
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:padding="15dp"
            android:text=""
            android:textColor="@color/font"
            android:textSize="15dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/send_btn"
            android:layout_width="35dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginHorizontal="5dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_send_black_24dp"
            />
    </TableRow>
</LinearLayout>
```

and have added the following `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize"`

Yet the keyboard still covers my editText. As you can see from the layout code the last table row contains an edit text where you can input text to send. I want it above the keyboard so you can see what you are typing. What is wrong with my layout?

Currently it looks like this:

[image]

EDIT :
I wrapped the last table row with a FrameLayout and everything is fine now.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your code add scrollview for the list.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    >

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:elevation="10dp"
                android:padding="10dp">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/listing_image"
                    android:layout_width="70dp"
                    android:layout_height="70dp"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/listing_title"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:text="Title"
                        android:textSize="16sp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/sdfsd"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:text="Listed by :" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/listing_author"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:text="Some random guy" />
                </LinearLayout>

            </TableRow>

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/listView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:divider="@null"
                android:stackFromBottom="false"
                android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/input_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Chat here..."
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:padding="15dp"
            android:text=""
            android:textSize="15dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/send_btn"
            android:layout_width="35dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginHorizontal="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_send" />
    </TableRow>
</LinearLayout>
```

[keyboard will not cover your edit text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pPw1E.png)